# how to turn off unnecessary log when start jetty?

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to embed jetty 9.4.21.v20190926. But it's show to much unnessary log like this:

```
  Server@239963d8{STARTED}[9.4.21.v20190926] - STARTED
    += QueuedThreadPool[qtp1268447657]@4b9af9a9{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=5,r=4,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@46daef40{s=0/4,p=0}] - STARTED
    |  += ReservedThreadExecutor@46daef40{s=0/4,p=0} - STARTED
    |  +> threads size=8
    |     +> 17 qtp1268447657-17 IDLE TIMED_WAITING @ sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    |     +> 12 qtp1268447657-12-acceptor-0@f5bee51-ServerConnector@7de26db8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:23689} ACCEPTING RUNNABLE @ sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) prio=3
sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)
    += ServerConnector@7de26db8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:23689} - STARTED
    |  +~ Server@239963d8{STARTED}[9.4.21.v20190926] - STARTED
    |  +~ QueuedThreadPool[qtp1268447657]@4b9af9a9{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=5,r=4,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@46daef40{s=0/4,p=0}] - STARTED
    |  += ScheduledExecutorScheduler@12f41634{STARTED} - STARTED
    |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.io.ArrayByteBufferPool@13c27452
    |  += HttpConnectionFactory@7637f22[HTTP/1.1] - STARTED
    |  |  +- HttpConfiguration@262b2c86{32768/8192,8192/8192,https://:0,[]}
    |  |     +> customizers size=0
    |  |     +> formEncodedMethods size=2
    |  |     |  +> POST
    |  |     |  +> PUT
    |  |     +> outputBufferSize=32768
    |  |     +> MANY THINGs......
    |  |     +> MANY THINGs......
    += ErrorHandler@2de8284b{STARTED} - STARTED
    += DefaultSessionIdManager@17d0685f{STARTED}[worker=node0] - STARTED
    |  += HouseKeeper@67b92f0a{STARTED}[interval=660000, ownscheduler=true] - STARTED
    +> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@12a3a380
       +> URLs size=18
       |  +> file:~lib/jetty-io-9.4.21.v20190926.jar
       |  +> MANY THINGs......
       |  +> file:~lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
       |  +> MANY THINGs......
       |  +> MANY THINGs......
       |  +> file:~build/classes/
       +> sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@396e2f39
          +> URLs size=12
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar


             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
             +> file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_211/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar
```

This hurts my eyes really pain. Is there anyway too reduce log like below?

```
2020-01-12 09:30:36.323:INFO::main: Logging initialized @285ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
 2020-01-12 09:30:37.139:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.21.v20190926; built: 2019-09-26T16:41:09.154Z; git: 72970db61a2904371e1218a95a3bef5d79788c33; jvm 1.8.0_211-b12
    2020-01-12 09:30:37.307:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
    2020-01-12 09:30:37.307:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
    2020-01-12 09:30:37.311:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
    2020-01-12 09:30:37.390:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@42f93a98{/,null,AVAILABLE}
    2020-01-12 09:30:37.762:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@7de26db8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:23689}
    2020-01-12 09:30:37.762:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1736ms
```

I only add  jetty.jar first then add all necessary jar via  error log when run.
As you seen, it's too much useless log that even made me to write more to post my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [jetty server dump](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-dump-tool.html). By default this is not displayed after startup but this can be configured through the server. In embedded code you can use `server.setDumpAfterStart(true/false)` to enable/disable this.